# Issue with Object Context Translate method for parent child object

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I have a Issue with EF for Object Context Translate Method.

I have created a View called PremiumCalculationASView as

```
 public class PremiumCalculationASView : BaseProposalASView
{
    public PreCalProView PreCalProView { get; set; }

    public PreCalInsView PreCalInsView { get; set; }

    public PreCalPolView PreCalPolView { get; set; }
}
```

And on this view I have a three property which is also a view. here is one of them

```
 public class PreCalPolView
{        
    [DataMember]       
    public bool PWRRider { get; set; }

    [DataMember]        
    public Int32 PremiumPayingTerm { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "Premium")]
    public decimal Premium { get; set; }
}
```

Now I am calling a stored procedure to fill PremiumCalculationASView Object as

```
public PremiumCalculationASView GetQuotationDetails(PremiumCalculationASView premiumCalculationView, string applicationConnectionString)
    {
        Database db = new Database(applicationConnectionString);
        DbConnection connection = null;
        DbCommand command = null;
        List<DbParameter> dbparams = new List<DbParameter>();
        var result = new List<PremiumCalculationASView>();

        try
        {
            db.AddInParam(dbparams, "PkQuotationId", DbType.Int32, premiumCalculationView.QuotationId);
            db.BuildOutParam(dbparams, "ErrorCode", DbType.String, 30);
            db.BuildOutParam(dbparams, "TotalRecords", DbType.String, 30);


            DbDataReader objReader = db.ExecuteReader(ref connection, ref command, "[eApp_GET_QUOTATION_DETAILS]", CommandType.StoredProcedure, dbparams.ToArray());
            using (var context = new OnlineSalesContainer())
            {
                //result.AddRange(context.Translate<PremiumCalculationASView>(objReader,));
                var preCalPolViewMap = new DataReaderAutoMap<PreCalPolView>();
                var premiumCalculationASViewMap = new DataReaderAutoMap<PremiumCalculationASView>()
                        .Specify((s, t) => t.PreCalPolView = preCalPolViewMap.Create(objReader));
                result = premiumCalculationASViewMap.CreateList(objReader);                    
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            db.CloseReader(ref connection, ref command);
        }
        return result[0];

    }
```

Now the issue is that PremiumCalculationASView root properties is get filled but the child object [PreCalInsView] properties is not getting filled.

I have check the SP its is returning the data which I have required and also the datamember name is also same in the SP.
Please let me know what I am doing wrong here.

**Edit**
Issue Resolved !
This is done by using anything-to-object mapping library on github: [Sixeyed.Mapping](https://github.com/sixeyed/projects/tree/master/Sixeyed.Mapping).

Comment: The sproc just returns flat results and `context.Translate` only handles flat results. It's not capable of creating an entire object graph. You'll have to build the objects yourself.

Comment: Thanks for you help @Gert Arnold. now I am using anything-to-object mapping library on github: [Sixeyed.Mapping](https://github.com/sixeyed/projects/tree/master/Sixeyed.Mapping).

Comment: Would you mind showing how you do this as an answer to your own question? This may be a promising approach, but the documentation of the library is `null`.

Comment: @GertArnold I haveupdated my question, please check **var preCalPolViewMap = new DataReaderAutoMap<PreCalPolView>();
                    var premiumCalculationASViewMap = new DataReaderAutoMap<PremiumCalculationASView>()
                            .Specify((s, t) => t.PreCalPolView = preCalPolViewMap.Create(objReader));
                    result = premiumCalculationASViewMap.CreateList(objReader);                    **

Comment: Please put this in an answer so we can read it. You can mark your own answer as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved this by using anything-to-object mapping library on github: [Sixeyed.Mapping](https://github.com/sixeyed/projects/tree/master/Sixeyed.Mapping).

With AutoMap method for datareader you can mapped object having same name as,

```
var preCalPolViewMap = new DataReaderAutoMap<PreCalPolView>();
            var premiumCalculationASViewMap = new DataReaderAutoMap<PremiumCalculationASView>()
                    .Specify((s, t) => t.PreCalPolView = preCalPolViewMap.Create(objReader));
            result = premiumCalculationASViewMap.CreateList(objReader);
```